# css table double border close cells at end

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have created as css to have borders so that the table looks like a grid with 1px. The first column is double border. The issue is the last row  first 2 cells are not closed due to double border. I cannot use at table level the border as it closes first row cells as well which is not required. The first row cell top border is set to white so that there is not border

I tried the box-layout css prop as well but this & border-top on table level introduces the table. I know i can add it in div so that div can have borders but am looking the best way to resolve this including it can anyway resolved using property been set either table, tr or td level.

Below is the table & the css or it can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/TcQ2j/.

```
<table class="tblplg sty4">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>8</td>
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>11</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>12</td>
                        <td>13</td>
                        <td>24</td>
                        <td>15</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table> 


<style type="text/css">
/*style4*/
.tblplg.sty4  {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    text-align: center;

}

.sty4 td {
         border: 1px solid black;
}

.sty4 td:first-child {
    text-align: left;   
}


.sty4 tr:first-child td{
    border-bottom: double   
}

.sty4 tr:first-child td:first-child{
    border-left: 0px;   
}

.sty4 tr:first-child td{
    border-top: 0px;    
}


.sty4 td:first-child {
         border-right: double;

}

.sty4 tr:last-child td {
         border-bottom: 0px;


}
/*style4*/
</style>
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. It also helps to make it include links with the code to jsfiddle so that we can play around with the code.

Comment: Ok.. i got this issue is only occuring in firefox in  IE this does not happen, any clue .. below is the link ==> http://jsfiddle.net/brijeshdkac/xKuJH/1/

Comment: what is this? `.sty4 tr:last-child td {
         border-bottom: 0px;


}` and what do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the cleanest answer but it certainly works.  Looks like its a browser interpretation of a double border that is causing the issue so I set your table to position relative and then used the :after pseudo element to add a a line that sits at the bottom of your table.

http://jsfiddle.net/xKuJH/5/

Comment: Glenn, if you can't get from text you can fdl link & do visual comparsion in FF & IE to see last row cells gap. I tried best to explain issue in words & in my last cmt did refer issue is in FF. Provided link as asked ..not sure what else better can i can do or u suggest. You can then try David link for soln to see gap at the last cell seen in FF, I guess it is postion:relative & .sty4:after css prop solved it. Gustonez, the .sty4 tr:last-child td { border-bottom: 0px; } is to remove last cell bottom border so that table bdr can be added, this was one of failed work around as explained.

Comment: I suggest remove flg as this issue & david soln might be helpful for many & make other understand issue & helpful for others looking for css. Thanks David I am still trying to understand the workaround & other ways to acheive but yours is perfectly working. thx again